# Android-How to make Notification(RemoteViews) support EditText?

Tags: android, notifications, android-edittext, remoteview

Is there a simple way?
or can I achieve this by adding a customized EditText in Android SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android-How to make Notification(RemoteViews) support EditText?

You would have to fork Android, modify it to support your desired feature, put your forked OS into a ROM mod, and install that on devices.

Comment: thanks for your replay:) Can I do this without a forked OS?